# Javascript Execute at end of Async Loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, asynchronous

I'm awful with Async code in Javascript and have been stuck on something for a while now.

I'm working with WebSql and just going through database initialization steps but one of the loops is not executing in the way I expect it to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initdatabase();
});

function initdatabase() {

    var db = window.openDatabase("nothing", "1.0", "nothing", 2 * 1024 * 1024);

    db.transaction(function(trans) {

        trans.executeSql("CREATE TABLE", [], function(trans, result) {
            // success
            defaultdata(db);
        }, function(error) {
            // failed
        });

    });

}

function defaultdata(db) {

    db.transaction(function(trans) {

        var lo_data = [
        {code:"CODE01", desc:"Code 01 Desc"},
        {code:"CODE02", desc:"Code 02 Desc"},
        {code:"CODE03", desc:"Code 03 Desc"}
        ];

        for(i = 0; i < lo_data.length; i++) {

            trans.executeSql("INSERT", [lo_data[i].code, lo_data[i].desc], function(trans, result) {
                // success
                console.log("INS : " + i);
            }, function(error) {
                // failed
            });

        }

        console.log("END");

    });

}
```

But the log to indicate the end is executing before the for loop has finished. If I try validate that the data has been inserted I always get fails because the loop hasn't completed the inserts.

Google says that async code should be handled with promises but I can't find examples of promises being used in an instance like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Steps to follow: 1.) Read what a [Promise](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) is carefully. 2.) Think about how the thing you just learned can be applied to your current problem. 3.) Perform code changes.

Comment: I understand promises for general use, a function will return a resolve or reject and then chain a second function but the loop would have multiple resolves

Answer (score 1):

Convert each callback into a promise, and then use Promise.all

```js
    const loDataPromises = lo_data.map(({ code, desc }) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        trans.executeSql(
          "INSERT",
          [code, desc],
          function(trans, result) {
            console.log('success');
            resolve();
          },
          function(error) {
            console.log('failed');
            reject();
          }
        );
      });
    });

    Promise.all(loDataPromises)
      .then(() => {
        console.log('all done');
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find any clear code examples on the internet so I wanted to post the working version here as the answer. Hopefully it can benefit someone also trying to understand promises and promise loops.

After a complete overhaul I've managed to get it working in a way that makes sense. I've change it to be executed as a promise chain and then the function with the for loop is utilizing the promise all logic.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   ////
   // promise chain
   ////

   console.log("BEGIN");
   f_initdatabase().then(function(result) {
      return f_defaultdata(result.db);
   }).then(function(result) {
      console.log("END");
   }).catch(function(result) {
      // abandon all hope
   });

});

////
// single promise usage
////

function f_initdatabase() {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

   console.log("   INIT DB");

   var lo_result = {db:null};

   var lv_db = window.openDatabase("thenothing", "1.0", "The Nothing DB", 2 * 1024 * 1024);

   lv_db.transaction(function(trans) {

      trans.executeSql ("create table if not exists dummydata (dd_idno integer primary key, dd_code text not null, dd_desc text not null)", [], function(trans, results) {
         console.log("   INIT DB : DONE");
         lo_result.db = lv_db;
         resolve(lo_result);
      }, function(error) {
         lo_result.db = null;
         reject(lo_result);
      });

   });

});
}

////
// loop promise all usage
////

function f_defaultdata(lv_db) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

   console.log("   DEF DATA");

   var lo_result = {db:null};

   lv_db.transaction(function(trans) {

      var la_promises = [];

      var lo_data = [
         {dd_code:"CODE01", dd_desc:"Code 01 Desc"},
         {dd_code:"CODE02", dd_desc:"Code 02 Desc"},
         {dd_code:"CODE03", dd_desc:"Code 03 Desc"}
      ];

      for(i = 0; i < lo_data.length; i++) {

         console.log("      INS : " + i);
         trans.executeSql (" insert into dummydata (dd_code, dd_desc) values (?, ?)", [lo_data[i].dd_code, lo_data[i].dd_desc], function(trans, results) {
            la_promises.push(resolve(lo_result));
         }, function(error) {
            la_promises.push(reject(lo_result));
         });

      }

      Promise.all(la_promises).then(function(results) {
         console.log("   DEF DATA : DONE");
         lo_result.db = lv_db;
         resolve(lo_result);
      }).catch(function() {
         lo_result.db = null;
         reject(lo_result);
      });

   });

});
}
```

This gives the output according to the flow needed

```
BEGIN
   INIT DB
   INIT DB : DONE
   DEF DATA
      INS : 0
      INS : 1
      INS : 2
   DEF DATA : DONE
END
```